# Can I toggle an image with Jquery, yet have live text upon click?

Tags: toggle, jquery

I'm not sure if my question makes sense, but,

I'm using jQuery to toggle an image from its off-state to its on-state upon click.
That was hard enough to get to work (I'm rather novice). 
The problem is that the on-state is an image with a fair amount of body copy. It obviously does not look as good as it would if it were live type.
I was wondering, if it's even possible, that the on-state be a div with live text that is hidden until the image is clicked.

I have no idea how to go about solving this problem as my knowledge of jQuery is rather limited.

The page is currently being hosted [here](http://melissa-athina.com/harbour1867/services.html)

Script:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        $("#click li").click(function (e) {
            $("#click li.selected").not(this).removeClass("selected");
            $(this).toggleClass("selected");
        });
    });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could include both a div -- initially hidden, with size matching the image -- and the image in each `li`.

CSS:

```
.imagetext {
  display: none;
  height: 50px; /* or whatever */
  width: 50px;
}

#click li img {
  display: block;
  height: 50px; /* or whatever */
  width: 50px;
}
#click li.selected img {
  display: none;
}

#click .imagetext {
  display: block;
}
```

HTML along the lines of:

```
<div id="#click">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <img src="..." />
      <div class="imagetext">Four score and seven...</div>
    </li>
    <!-- ... -->
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you to the moon and back!